# VM Gaming via GPU Passthrough without a dedicated monitor?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, games

I'm looking at building a computer that can virtualize two or more gaming machines at once. I'm hoping to be able to play two (or more) games at the same time, and I'm hoping to be able to display them both on the same monitor at the same time.

The intuitive way of making this work would be to use the "window" you normally get when running a basic Virtual Machine, but you don't seem to get this when using GPU passthrough. Are there any VM suites that can use GPU passthrough and still display the GPU's output on the "host machine's" monitor?

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Edit**: try [Looking Glass](https://github.com/gnif/LookingGlass), it's been around for a few years now and people are having great, low latency results (i.e., usable for gaming).

Original 2016 response:

I don't think this is currently possible. The most sensible I've seen is plugging both GPU cards into the same monitor, and using that monitor's input switching features when you want to flip between your host and your guest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, but you'll need an HDMI Dummy Plug. I'm using:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07YKGGQTJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I've got an old lenovo TS140 running VMWARE, with a GTX 1050 ti in pass through to a Win10 Box, running Steam.

In theory, you could use one GPU like this, running steam link (thus the rendering is done on the Virtual machine) and run a second game (which would use local rendering).

I can then use Steam Link on the raspberry Pi devices around the house to run games.

If you use VMware in my setup, when you setup the VM you need to:
-> Click Actions
-> Edit Settings
-> VM Options Button
-> Advanced
-> Edit Configuration
-> Add Parameter
-> hypervisor.cpuid.v0 and set it to FALSE

Also be sure to set the GPU in the PCI pass through and in the host "Manage -> Hardware -> Toggle passthrough".